# Why is Excel able to complete resource-intensive formulas only when restarted through Task Manager?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, freeze

This morning I was fumbling around with various iterations of `IF(COUNTIF())` in one column for 16,000 rows.  I've experienced how slow the `COUNTIF()` function can be, so I wasn't surprised to see it freeze Excel.

I did get frustrated when every single time I amended this formula for the entire column, it *always* froze Excel.  I would open task manager, end task, select "Restart Program".  I noticed that each time I restarted Excel, cells of the re-opened document reflected the formulaic changes I tried to implement.

So, when I would try to apply a new `IF(COUNTIF())` function to these 16, 000 cells, it would always freeze indefinitely, unable to execute the change.  But each time I would restart Excel through the task manager, it would then reflect the changes.

I would think that Excel's ability to handle a set of calculations would be a binary option: either it can or cannot perform the task with available resources.  Why is it only able to do so when re-started?

Comment: Let's say you use the `countif` at column A. In your `if` you go for column 's `B:H`. Entering something in `B:H` will trigger all `countif`. Better set your `countif` in a helper column (this way it doesn't need to calculate it every time)... if you get what I mean...

Comment: Why was this down voted? Is the question not site-relevant or is it written ambiguously? If the former, what site should this be on? If the latter, where does the ambiguity lie? If neither, what needs clarified to make this a better question?

Answer (score 0):

What takes so long is the *calculation*, of course not the storing of you change. When you kill Excel and started again you get the old (now incorrect) values shown and the new formula stored. You are basically killing the recalculation. It will still take that long next time...

Consider that your COUNTIF has to loop through many cells, maybe the same 16000 (I wouldn't know what you have in there); this formula is copied 16000 times. That means there are 256 million loop cycles to do. For *each* one, the comparison you have inside the COUNTIF needs to be interpreted and evaluated.

It will be a bit faster the second time you run it (after it finished once), I think because excel remembers internally that all your formulas were the same syntax and so it does not need to interpret them again. Still, the calculation will have to be repeated, 256 million times.